# Show/hide jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, show-hide

I have a problem with my code, I don't know why it doesn't work. 
My goal is to have my default:

EN div with only `#en` div visible, FR & DE id must be hidden by default.
When we click on FR or DE, we have only `#fr` or `#de` visible and the rest hidden.

HERE IS MY [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/4nsr032L/)

HERE IS MY CODE:

```js
    $('#en').click(function(){
    $('fr[id^=fr], de[id^=de]').hide();
    $('#en1, #en2').show();
    });

    $('#fr').click(function(){
    $('en[id^=en], de[id^=de]').hide();
    $('#fr1, #fr2').show();
    });

    $('#de').click(function(){
    $('fr[id^=fr], en[id^=en]').hide();
    $('#de1, #de2').show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button" id="en">EN</a>
    <a class="button" id="fr">FR</a>
    <a class="button" id="de">DE</a>
    <div id="en1">1</div>
    <div id="fr1">2</div>
    <div id="de1">3</div>
    <div id="en2">4</div>
    <div id="fr2">5</div>
    <div id="de2">6</div>
```

Comment: You have to include jQuery in your code first

Comment: How I have to do that ?

Comment: By adding `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` on top of your html. [Here](https://code.jquery.com/) is source of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle of how I think should this code work:
http://jsfiddle.net/MJambazov/tdeotges/1/

Try to follow the DRY principle, it will make your code more readable for humans.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lan').hide();
  $('.en').show();
});

$('.button').click(function(event) {
  $('.lan').hide();
  var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
  var setActiveLanguage = "." + selectedLanguage;
  $(setActiveLanguage).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is repeated in your selectors like:

```
$('fr[id^=fr], de[id^=de]')
```

This must be changed to:

```
$('div[id^=fr], div[id^=de]')
```

In order to have as default the en only visible it is enough to append to the click event a trigger click.

The snippet and [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nsr032L/5/):

```js
$('#en').click(function(){
  $('div[id^=fr], div[id^=de]').hide();
  $('#en1, #en2').show();
}).trigger('click');

$('#fr').click(function(){
  $('div[id^=en], div[id^=de]').hide();
  $('#fr1, #fr2').show();
});

$('#de').click(function(){
  $('div[id^=fr], div[id^=en]').hide();
  $('#de1, #de2').show();
});
```

```css
.button { cursor:pointer; padding: 0px 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="button" id="en">EN</a>
<a class="button" id="fr">FR</a>
<a class="button" id="de">DE</a>


<div id="en1">1</div>
<div id="fr1">2</div>
<div id="de1">3</div>
<div id="en2">4</div>
<div id="fr2">5</div>
<div id="de2">6</div>
```

Comment: you are totally right I understand my error, thanks a lot that's exactly what i was looking for ;D you rock

Answer (score 0):

So in your fiddle you were missing jQuery like the comments mentioned above.
First, in order to have a default you need to add a hidden class.

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

This will allow you to set the default hidden tags.

```
<a class="button" id="en">EN</a>
<a class="button" id="fr">FR</a>
<a class="button" id="de">DE</a>

<div id="en1">1</div>
<div class="hidden" id="fr1">2</div>
<div class="hidden" id="de1">3</div>
<div id="en2">4</div>
<div class="hidden" id="fr2">5</div>
<div class="hidden" id="de2">6</div>
```

You were also pointing to the incorrect selectors you were pointing to fr[id^=fr] and same for the others. You should replace that with div[id^=country].

```
$('#en').click(function(){
   $('div[id^=fr], div[id^=de]').hide();
   $('#en1, #en2').show();
});

$('#fr').click(function(){
   $('div[id^=en], div[id^=de]').hide();
   $('#fr1, #fr2').show();
});

$('#de').click(function(){
   $('div[id^=fr], div[id^=en]').hide();
   $('#de1, #de2').show();
});
```